# VBA Code for Avaya CMS won't run on different users

Tags: excel, vba, avaya

In our call center we use Excel VBA to extract integrated data through Avaya CMS supervisor. We have been using the same code for years.

One of our supervisors cannot run the report with her windows NT login. She receives the OLE timeout error when attempting. Every other user can run the report if they attempt to use their NT at the same computer.

We don't have anyone who knows VBA or Avaya well enough to troubleshoot (a temp was hired to code). I am intermediate level at best and find nothing wrong with the logic - as I said earlier it runs fine for me.

When I asked our dedicated IT department if this could be a user profile issue they informed me all supervisors have the same "cookie cutter" profile given to them. They state it has to be an issue with the VBA code.

**Is there any other troubleshooting methods I can attempt at this point?** Besides user permissions with Avaya and the code itself is there anything else that could interfere with VBA? Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, they say it's cookie cutter, but there's one little bit they forgot to flip. In could be in VBA, but it's not VBA specific. It's something in the business logic and only reviewing the code will reveal that. Search the code for your username and see if the temp hard coded some stuff that has to be updated (or better yet refactored). My money is on NT permissions, but if it's in the code nobody will be able to fix it without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that it could be an issue with the User Account Control (UAC), if that supervisor has it set on a higher level than others. When the UAC is turned on, it restricts what you can do in VBA. To check the UAC level, open the control panel, then 'User Accounts', 'Change User Account Control settings'

One alternative to using Excel VBA to extracting data is to use a web browser based reporting tool with full permission controls that exports regularly to Excel. NetLert's N-Focus Plus reporting tool can do that - it pulls data from CMS, stores it to a database on a server (as a result, you can store unlimited historical interval data), lets you set up any number of permissions for unlimited 'supervisors' so they only see their data or their groups' data, and they can export reports to excel or set up their own automatic daily/weekly/monthly report distribution. It also ties multiple CMS servers together in a single web-based interface, and does real-time and historical reporting... check it out at http://www.netlert.com/nfocus_video_overview.php

Comment: The user levels seems to have fixed the issue. We're not about to use a new reporting tool when we already have a trusted one, but thanks for telling me about netlert.